# Недавно полученные знаки скучковались

Tags: дефект, дизайн

[image: скриншот знаков]

Думаю, между знаками по вертикали должна быть какая-то пустота - как между метками:

[image: скриншот меток]

Comment: Ну да кстати, уже несколько дней как, и я это заметил. Подумал, что теперь так и должно быть. А ведь с отступом получше было и правда.

Comment: Баг-репорт на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360533/339911)